# ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.

Tags: python, python-3.5

Can someone help me out I get this error when I run my file
ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.
I am just trying to run a simle test file that says 
one
two
three
four
five
six
seven
eight
nine
ten

```
def main():
# Declare variables
line = ''
counter = 0

# Prompt for file name
fileName = input('Enter the name of the file: ')

# Open the specified file for reading
infile = open(fileName, 'r')

# Priming read
line = infile.readline()
counter = 1

# Read in and display first five lines
while line != '' and counter <= 5:
# Strip '\n'
    line = line.rstrip('\n')
    print(line)
    line = infile.readline()
    # Update counter when line is read
    counter +=1  

# Close file
    infile.close()

# Call the main function.
main()
```

Comment: You closed `infile` in the `while` loop.

Comment: You may want to look into the `with open() as...` syntax for reading files

Comment: Add `print('closing file')` right before the close... you'll see it twice.

Comment: Fix your indentation.

Answer (score 3):

In Python indentation is part of syntax - it denotes code blocks.

Your code snippet clearly shows that `infile.close()` operation is *inside* a loop, so it's executed on first iteration. Second read from file therefore fails, because file was already closed in previous iteration.

Simply detent line `infile.close()` to fix.

Alternatively, use context managers to allow Python manage resource clean up.

```
with open(fileName, 'r') as infile:
    pass  # operate on file here

# file will be closed automatically when you leave code block above.
```